# How do Rényi entropies act under unitary time evolution?

Tags: unitarity, information-theory, entropy

I am trying to find information/ help on Rényi entropies given by
$$ S_n(\rho) = \frac{1}{1-n} \ln [Tr(\rho^n)] $$

and how it acts under unitary time evolution? Is the entropy independent on the state of $\rho$ i.e it doesn't matter if $\rho$ is pure or mixed? I am also unsure on how to apply Von Neumann's equation
$$ \rho(t) = U(t, t_0) \rho(t_0) U^{\dagger} (t, t_0) $$
In order to see how it acts.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$
\rho(t)=U\rho U^\dagger,
$$
just to simplify notation a bit. Now notice that
$$
\rho(t)^2=U\rho U^\dagger U\rho U^\dagger=U\rho^2 U^\dagger
$$
since $U^\dagger U=I$. Thus, similarly,
$$
\rho(t)^n=U\rho^n U^\dagger.
$$
So, take the trace of this, remembering that trace is invariant under permutations:
$$
\text{Tr}(\rho(t)^n)=\text{Tr}(U\rho^n U^\dagger)=\text{Tr}(\rho^n U^\dagger U)=\text{Tr}(\rho^n).
$$
Thus,
$$
S_n(\rho(t))=S_n(\rho).
$$

Answer (score 3):

They are invariant under conjugation of unitaries, i.e. under the mapping $\rho \to U \rho U^*$. To see this note that $(U \rho U^*)^{\alpha} = U \rho^\alpha U^*$. Then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_\alpha(U \rho U^*) &= \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log \mathrm{Tr}[(U \rho U^*)^{\alpha}] \\
&= \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log \mathrm{Tr}[U \rho^\alpha U^*] \\ 
&= \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log \mathrm{Tr}[U^* U \rho^{\alpha}] \\
&= \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log \mathrm{Tr}[\rho^\alpha] \\
&= S_\alpha(\rho).
\end{aligned}
$$

On the second line we used the above identity, on the third line we used cyclicity of the trace and on the fourth line we used $U^* U = I$ as $U$ is unitary.